# Forget Wi-Fi network Android feature not working

Tags: android

I am using below code to forget Wi-Fi network from CODE:

```
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
       wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
       wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

On Android "O" if Wi-Fi is connected through my application then it's able to forget it however if I connect Wi-Fi through Android OS setting then it's not forgetting the Wi-Fi. Somewhere I read it is a known issue and have to provide permission `WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN` and need to root device.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Android M apps are not allowed to modify networks that they did not create.
See here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37062809
And here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-network

Comment: You are not permitted to modify or delete WifiConfiguration objects created by the user or by other apps.